# SSRS BIDS 2008 data labels placement expression

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, expression, bids

See attached image.

I have clicked 'Show data Labels' on my bubble diagram, this is now displaying the project name over each bubble which is fine. What I want is to add an expression to the position (See far right red circle)

The expression I would like is the ability to say "Show data labels bottom right if the project is less than or equal to 50 percent complete (see vertical exis [Complete] field)"

Firstly is this possible, if so what would the expression be.

The fields that you need are:

BarName = Project Name
Complete = % Complete

[image]

Comment: I think the expression may need to go in series label properties > Label data > expression

Answer (score 2, accepted):

=iif(Fields!Complete.Value <= 50,Fields!BarName.Value,"")